# Notification icon that looks like 4 patches stitch together (shaped like Windows icon)

Tags: notification-icons

What is the circled icon that looks like 4 patches stitch together (shaped like Windows icon) circled in blue is for?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty easy to figure out app icon on notification panel , downloaded from Google Play Store

- App notification icons *usually* are on the left half of notification panel
- *Google Play → My Apps and Games → Installed*  brings up all apps on your phone. Just scroll through and match with icon on notification panel
- *Google Play → My Apps and Games → All*  brings up all apps you downloaded , including on your earlier devices. This icon was familiar since I had used it on my earlier device and matching icons tells me it is [AVG Antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antivirus). Thanks to Mathew and Vivek confirming same in comments